# Delete account with password verification

Tags: php, password-encryption, password-hash

i have this solution for user to delete his account (it is working pretty well)

```
        if(!empty($_POST['delete'])){
    
    if(empty($_POST['currentpassword'])) {
            $error = error('Please enter current password.');
    }

    $SQLCheckCurrent = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = :ID AND `password` = :currentpassword");
    $SQLCheckCurrent -> execute(array(':ID' => $_SESSION['ID'], ':currentpassword' => SHA1(md5($_POST['currentpassword']))));
    $countCurrent = $SQLCheckCurrent -> fetchColumn(0);

    if ($countCurrent == 0){
        $error = error('Current password is incorrect.');
    }
    
    $notify = error($error);

    if(empty($error)){
        $SQLUpdate = $odb -> prepare("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `ID` = :id");
        $SQLUpdate -> execute(array(':username' => $_SESSION['username'], ':id' => $_SESSION['ID']));
        session_destroy();
        header("location: login");
        die();
    }

}
```

I recently changed everything from MD5 to the newer `password_hash` but I can not update this part sadly, I have tried this but no luck so far

```
        if(!empty($_POST['delete'])){
    
    if(empty($_POST['currentpassword'])) {
            $error = error('Please enter current password.');
    }

    $SQLCheckCurrent = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = :ID AND `password` = :currentpassword");
    $SQLCheckCurrent -> execute(array(':ID' => $_SESSION['ID'], ':currentpassword' => password_verify($_POST['currentpassword'],$userInfo['password'])));
    $countCurrent = $SQLCheckCurrent -> fetchColumn(0);

    if ($countCurrent == 0){
        $error = error('Current password is incorrect.');
    }
    
    $notify = error($error);

    if(empty($error)){
        $SQLUpdate = $odb -> prepare("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `ID` = :id");
        $SQLUpdate -> execute(array(':username' => $_SESSION['username'], ':id' => $_SESSION['ID']));
        session_destroy();
        header("location: login");
        die();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to read first about how to use password_verify, that because **password_verify** only return boolean that give you **TRUE/FALSE**. So, you can't use that function to check the data in the DB.

Read about password_verify here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

And then, for the solution, you can change the logic of your code like here:

**1. Get the saved password by ID only (make your own query)**, e.g. I will call it `$saved_password`

```php
$saved_password = '...'; // Get the password from DB by user id
```

**2. Verify the given password with saved password**

```php
if (password_verify($_POST['currentpassword'], $saved_password)) {
  // Password verified
  // DELETE THE USER
} else {
  // Error. The password is wrong!
}
```

That's it, hope this can help you.